# How to exclude a property when using the RequestFactory in GWT

Tags: hibernate, gwt, requestfactory

I'am using the RequestFactory to retrieve a list of objects from the server. Now I want to exclude the "description" (String) property of the object which can contains a long text.

Is there any way to do that in RequestFactory at Runtime?

This is how I retrieve the list

```
    collectcontextProvider.get().getListObject().fire(
    new Receiver<List<ObjectProxy>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess (List<ObjectProxy> objectList) {
        //display the list
        }           

        @Override
        public void onFailure(ServerFailure error) {
            //Error
          }
        });
```

I use Hibernate

Comment: May there is something equivalent to the `@transient` annotation ?

Comment: I need the exclusion at Runtime (edited my question). Something opposite to with()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the description field in other places of your app, you'll want a trimmed-down proxy that does not expose that property, and of course a service method that returns a list of such proxies.

```java
@ProxyFor(value=MyObject.class, locator=MyLocator.class)
interface MyObjectLiteProxy extends EntityProxy {
   // all properties but 'description'
}

@ProxyFor(value=MyObject.class, locator=MyLocator.class)
interface MyObjectProxy extend MyObjectLiteProxy {
   String getDescription();
}

@Service(MyService.class)
interface CollectContext extends RequestContext {
   Request<List<MyObjectLiteProxy>> getListObjectLite();

   Request<List<MyObjectProxy>> getListObject();
}
```

Actually, you could even go farther and use the same `MyService` implementation for 2 `RequestContext`s:

```java
@Service(MyService.class)
interface CollectLiteContext extends RequestContext {
   Request<List<MyObjectLiteProxy>> getListObject();
}

@Service(MyService.class)
interface CollectContext extends RequestContext {
   Request<List<MyObjectProxy>> getListObject();
}
```

Comment: Basically the properties that are exposed in the proxy are the ones  retrieved by the RequestFactory.